# EQing the reverb

Tags: eq, reverb

i would like to know if you guys EQ a reverb, if so what parameters do you keep in mind while doing so? everytime i try to EQ a reverb i end up fiddling with it without getting proper results..i have tried using Rverb.
or may be can someone explain why we need to eq a reverb in first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I almost always end up EQing my reverbs, although sometimes convolution reverb presets work without alteration. It truly depends on what you are sending to the reverb and what else is happening in the mix. Un-EQed reverb usually covers the full frequency spectrum, and if you're talking about many elements in a mix then adding broadband reverb can result in a layer of distracting "soup" that muddies up your other mix elements.

I would suggest experimenting with putting the EQ before the reverb in the signal chain. If you feel that there is too much bass boominess in your reverb, for instance, try inserting an EQ before the reverb and shelving out the bass there—then perhaps add a subtle boost in the frequency range where you want the reverb to sit. It makes for a much more natural reverb sound when it works. If you still feel you are not getting the results you're looking for, consider a different reverb preset or plugin (if this is available to you).

If you know you have the right setup and it's still not working for you, then add an EQ post-reverb. Always start by working in simple, broad EQ strokes (high- and low-shelves are your friend) as this will keep the overall tone of the reverb more natural.

Good luck!
~Matt

Answer (score 1):

I use EQ on a reverb to try and recreate the surfaces that are present in the room that I am trying to simulate. If there is plaster board, I will roll of some of the top end, if there is stone I roll off more of the bass.  If the space is mostly glass then high mids will be important.  I will also consider the likelihood of room modes and EQ accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I do a good amount of music as well as sound design and mix and yes I eq verb much of the time, even if that means using the shelving parameters that exist in many verb plugs. Also like Matt mentioned, often times it is a matter of eqing the signal going into to the verb. It is common for me to filter a bit of the bass out of the signal before it hits the verb to keep it more clean down low. As a generality, things can get muddy quickly when verb is applied to bass. Washing out the low end is often times trouble so applying a high pass to a desired taste to the signal going in can help keep a mix clean down low and still give you nice ambiance up above, this is especially true if you are bussing multiple signals/channels into one verb on an aux for example. You can then push more reverberant signal if you like without muddying up your low end.